# R - Concatenating strings with escape characters

Tags: r, escaping, concatenation

I am trying to create a multi-line string in R out of several other strings and adding line breaks with `/n`. When I use `paste` I do not get a new line i simply get "\n" concatenated in with my strings.

```
 x <- "hello"
 y <- "world
 paste(x,"\n",y)

 # [1] "hello \n world"
```

I would line to get something along the lines of:

```
 hello
 world
```

I know that `cat` would output the correct answer to the console but I would like to store this multi-line string in a variable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `\n` **is** a new line. `cat` will actually make the line break when it prints to console, `print()` will not. But in both cases, it is a multiline string.

Comment: The paste does return a multi-line string. It's just that R escapes the newline as "\n" in the console. If you write that to a file, you'll see that it creates two lines. I'm not sure exactly what the problem is. Is there some down stream thing that isn't working for you?

Comment: I was testing it in the console before I wrote the string to a file, I will implement it like I have it and see if it does come out on several lines.